# Extending sapui5 applications: How to hide a field inside a fragment?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to extend a standard sapui5 application, in which i need to hide some fields using eclipse IDE.

**The Problem:**
I can't figure out how to hide a field from a fragment. Until now i am only able to hide fields from views.

**What procedure is required to hide a field from a fragment?**

This is the metadata code that i used to hide a label and an input from a view:

```
metadata:{
/*meta data details like configuration, customizing, and routing data*/
    customizing: {  
        "sap.ui.viewModifications": {
            "mytravelandexpense.view.S3": {
                "statutoryTypeLabel": {
                    "visible": false
                },
                "statutoryTypeInput": {
                    "visible": false
                }
            }
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I haven't extended Controls yet but i think i can give you a hint in the right directions

You cannot use the reference to the view mytravelandexpense to hide a field from a fragment (the fragment doesn't belongs to the view, it's an independent part of the code). You need to hide the field of the fragment within the correct reference:

I would try to add something like this in the metadata:

```
 "myFragmentname.fragment.S3": {
                "myFieldToHide": {
                    "visible": false
                }
 }
```

I haven't looked closer into this document but it seems to be the right information: http://a248.g.akamai.net/n/248/420835/f21c2e0265fa7f1328364d22a2cb77e8655ea870cd777c3d90657faf63c79587/sapasset.download.akamai.com/420835/sapcom/docs/2015/08/8ea85c27-5a7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.pdf